# Show, that the intersection of two manifolds $M, N \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ doesn't need to be a manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds

I've got some ideas on how to tackle it, but I don't know what I should do:

1. To choose such a $M$ and $N$ that it's intersection is the empty set (or a set of meassure zero maybe, maybe something with the Cantor set, or to choose $M$ and $N$ as a countable set, or choose $M$ or $N$ as just the empty set?)
2. To choose such a $M$ and $N$, that there exists some $x \in M \cap N$ that it's transition function is not a homomorphism (might be trickier to show that)

I don't know how to start here, but here are my ideas. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intersection of topological manifolds.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394276/intersection-of-topological-manifolds)

Comment: Please make it a habit to include the full problem statement in the body of your Question.   It is fine to give the title as you did; it does let Readers surmise what the Question is about.  But it leaves doubt about whether some assumptions have been omitted to fit the length of a title, and it makes it harder to piece together the problem statement with your contextual remarks.

Comment: @C.F.G No, it does give examples, but it doesn't explain why those examples are no manifolds, and that's what I ultimately need

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**

Look at the intersection of the lateral surfaces of two cylinders with the same radii, coplanar and orthogonal axis.

The intersection is not a manifold. It is however the union of two manifolds.

Comment: What does "coplanar and orthogonal axis" mean?

Comment: And **why** exactly is the intersection of such two cylinders not a manifold? Why are even those two cylinders manifolds in the first place?

Comment: @anon You're asking questions that (1) for the first one will be answered by wikipedia and (2) for the second one if you look at the definition of manifolds in a course on the topic. I imagine that you're studying one?

Comment: A manifold $M$ is a topological Hausdorff space where for any point $p \in M$ there exists a map $(U, \phi)$. So why are cylinders Hausdorff spaces, and why should there for any $x \in \text{cylinder}$ exist a map $(U, \phi)$? And why is the intersection of cylinders not? I'm sorry if I keep asking such questions, but we don't really have the best course in Differential Geometry, the lecture and tutoring completely differ from each other.

Comment: @anon [Cylinder](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Cylinder.html)

Comment: And where does it say why a cylinder is a manifold? I literally only got the definition from the lecture which was shortly mentioned: A manifold $M$ is a topological Hausdorff space where for any point $p \in M$ there exists a map $(U, \phi)$

Comment: Remember @mathcounterexamples [Enforcement of Quality Standards](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=Enforcement+of+Quality+Standards). As you answered another problem statement question by a "no clue how to proceed" plea.