# intersecting *semi-riemannian* manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, reference-request, semi-riemannian-geometry, transversality

I read this interesting post: [Intersection of manifolds](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1394276/460999).

In geometry/topology one can consider intersection of manifolds (which need not be a manifold). I'm curious if one can do this in Semi-Riemannian geometry in a meaningful way?

Specifically I guess:

> Has anyone ever studied in general, the problem of $k$ intersecting solutions to the EFE with cosmological constants?

And is there any motivation to study this?

Some extra conditions may be that the resulting structure is again a solution to the EFE. I think one would unfortunately have to drop the property of causality.