# Show or disprove that the intersection of two submanifolds a submanifold iff the intersection is nonempty.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, functions, proof-writing, manifolds

My attempt at a solution:

Let M and N be k-dimensional submanifolds of $R^n$. For all $m \in M$, there exists $T \subset R^k$, an environment $U \subset R^n$ around m, and an immersion $\phi: T \to M$ so that $\phi(T) = M \cap U$. Moreover, for all $n \in N$, there exists $S \subset R^k$, an environment $V \subset R^n$ around n, and an immersion $\psi: S \to N$ so that $\psi(S) = N \cap V$.

Now consider an arbitrary point $p \in M \cup N$. Since p is an element of M, it is equipped with T, U, and $\phi$ so that $\phi(p) = p \cap U$ and it is also equipped with S, V, and $\psi$ so that $\psi(p) = p \cap V$.

I'm not sure where to go from here. I think that because the immersion is clearly determined, $\phi = \psi$ and the intersection would be a submanifold itself. However, I am very new at this.

Comment: The intersection of two manifolds is in general not a manifold. You can realise a figure eight (not a manifold) as the intersection of a torus and a plane (both manifolds).

Comment: See here how bad it can get https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1394276/intersection-of-topological-manifolds